# How to read preauthorize expression from yaml file

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-el

How to read `@Preauthorize` expression from property file?

I have expression in yaml file:

```
authorize:
     exp: hasAnyAuthority('ROLE_XXX')
```

```java
@PreAuthorize("${authorize.exp}")
public void blah(){
    //something
}
```

SpelParseException is being thrown for above implementation.

Below is the stacktrace:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException: EL1041E:(pos 1): After parsing a valid expression, there is still more data in the expression: 'lcurly({)'
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.InternalSpelExpressionParser.doParseExpression(InternalSpelExpressionParser.java:129)
```

I tried `@PreAuthorize("#{authorize.exp}")`, but same exception.
I don't want boolean to be read from property file, I want expression to be read.